# Triggering handleEvent() from addEventListener in an es6 class

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener, es6-class

I learned yesterday that with `addEventListener` you can pass an object with a `handleEvent()` method instead of a callback function and so I am trying to make this work.

I am referring to [this article](https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/handleevent), as well as a few other ones explaining the same thing.

I think my code is correct, but I am getting an error: `menuBuilder.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: toggleMobileNav.addEventListener is not a function`

Here is what I have essentially:

```js
class menuBuilder {
  constructor() {
    this.addMobileNavEventListeners();
  }

  handleEvent(event) {
    if (event.type === 'click') {
      // Close the Submenus from Mobile Nav
      if (event.target.closest('.mobile-control-close-submenus')) {
        this.submenus.close();
      }

      // Open / Close Mobile Nav
      if (event.target.closest('.mobile-control-toggle-nav')) {
        this.toggleMobile();
      }
    }
  }

  addMobileNavEventListeners() {
    // Adds Event Listeners for mobile nav...
    // Close Submenu from Mobile Nav
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".mobile-control-close-submenus")].forEach((closeSubMenusIcon) => closeSubMenusIcon.addEventListener("click", this, false));

    // Open / Close Mobile Nav
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.mobile-control-toggle-nav')].forEach((toggleMobileNav) => toggleMobileNav.addEventListener("click", this, false));
  }
}
```

I'm pretty new to es6 & vanilla javascript. I've been living in jQuery land for way too long but I am getting the hang of things (I think, haha) Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: What is `this.elements.mobileNavToggles` ?

Comment: @Titus its a nodelist from `document.querySelectorAll('.mobile-control-toggle-nav')`. oops.

Comment: I don't think that the code in your question will cause that error.